# Placing Existing Div into a DOM div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a div that I have created with DOM/JS. I have another div that that I have some html in that i would like to place inside of the DOM div. I;m quite new to JS so any help would be appreciated.

```js
//The DOM div

div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "0px";  
div.style.top = "0px";
div.style.width = "240px";
div.style.height = "auto";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.padding = "15px 0px 0px 0px";
div.style.color = "white";
div.id = "chat";
```

```html
<!--The existing div code-->

<div id="page-wrap">

  <h2>Chat</h2>
  <p id="name-area"></p>
  <div id="chat-wrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>
  <form id="send-message-area">
      <p>Your message: </p>
      <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: if I place a div around my existing div and give it an ID would append child work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` property like the following way:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "0px";  
div.style.top = "0px";
div.style.width = "240px";
div.style.height = "auto";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.padding = "15px 0px 0px 0px";
div.style.color = "white";
div.id = "chat";

//
div.innerHTML += document.getElementById('page-wrap').outerHTML;
document.getElementById('page-wrap').remove(); // remove the previous one;
document.body.append(div);
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">

    <h2>Chat</h2>

    <p id="name-area"></p>

    <div id="chat-wrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p>Your message: </p>
        <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I have one issue with this. The div is being placed inside of the other div but is still existing on the page. So instead of being placed inside of the DOM div it's being copied and there are two instances. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: @STOAM, you can remove the previous element with `remove()`, updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already created your divElement, you will just need to get the div in your Html using either id/class etc... example :

```
var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('chat-area')
```

And then you would simply append your created div as so :

```
htmlDiv.append(myCreatedDiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild` method to add element into another (pure JavaScript)

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div2 = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(div2);
```

Alternative is jQuery's `append` as yahya mentioned, which uses the `appendChild` method internally.